# Mysql RANK is not giving RANK for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried following thing but it is not ranking each category wise. Instead giving rank for all records without considering category. I want the RANK to re-occur for each category

```
select  rs.Section,rs.Field1,rs.Field2 , 
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
from (
select rs.Field1,rs2.Field2 
from table rs
inner join table2 rs2 on rs.Field1=rs2.Field1
group by rs.Section,rs.Field1 
)rs,  (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
```

**Actual Output:** (From Mysql Output )

```
Category Field1 Field2 Rank
Male     10     10     1
Male     11     10     2
Male     12     10     3
....
FeMale   10     10     11
FeMale   11     10     12
FeMale   12     10     13
....
```

**Expected Output**

```
Category Field1 Field2 Rank
Male     10     10     1
Male     11     10     2
Male     12     10     3
....
FeMale   10     10     1
FeMale   11     10     2
FeMale   12     10     3
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the query you are working with is:

```
select  rs.Category, rs.Field1, rs.Field2, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
from (select rs.Cateogry, rs.Field1, rs2.Field2 
      from table rs inner join
           table2
           rs2 on rs.Field1 = rs2.Field1
      group by rs.Category, rs.Field1, rs.Field2
     ) rs cross join
     (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
order by cateogry, field1;
```

Or something like this, where the field names are consistent.  You need a variable to specify the grouping.  This following will work:

```
select  rs.Category, rs.Field1, rs.Field2,
        (@curRank := if(@c = Category, @curRank + 1,
                        if(@c := Category, 1, 1)
                       )
        ) AS rank 
from (select rs.Cateogry, rs.Field1, rs2.Field2 
      from table rs inner join
           table2
           rs2 on rs.Field1 = rs2.Field1
      group by rs.Category, rs.Field1, rs.Field2
     ) rs cross join
     (SELECT @curRank := 0, @c := NULL) vars
order by cateogry, field1;
```

Note that the assignment of both variables occurs in one statement.  This is important because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select` clause.  Also note the explicit use of `group by`.  I suggest you use it and not depend on the `group by` producing the results in a particular order (that functionality is deprecated in the most recent version of MySQL).

Comment: Thanks. it works. But why should i not depend on GROUP BY for ordering result. Say i want to Filter order by category and field and after that apply filter on rank <10 , it can not be achieved if dont use GROUP BY instead of `order by cateogry, field1;`

Comment: @logan . . . Go to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html and search for "deprecated".

Comment: Thanks.. But other databases , its good to use group by.. And they suggest to avoid using order by . it's totally reverse in mysql ..